# Ajax Request not returning PHP Loop Echo

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The PHP is working fine when directly called in browser, but the `ajax.responseText` does not contain anything given out by the While Loop.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `Dienstplan` WHERE MONTH(Datum) = '$Monat'");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $Datum = $row['Datum'];
        $Datum = strtotime($Datum);
        $Datum = date('d.m.Y',$Datum);        
        $Tag = $row['Tag'];
        $Dienst = $row['Dienst'];

        //echo '<tr><td>'.$Tag.' '.$Datum.' '.$Dienst.'</td></tr>';
        echo $Tag.' '.$Datum.' '.$Dienst.'';        
}
echo "This is a Test!";
```

The `ajax.responseText` only contains the last `echo` after the While Loop. But when I call the PHP script directly in my Browser I can clearly see all the data given out by the loop. For some reason it's not contained in the Ajaxresponse.

Here is the Ajax Code:

```
var ajax;
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET","../php/FTL_Month_2.php",true);
ajax.send();

ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200){
            //alert(ajax.responseText);
            document.getElementById("DataList").innerHTML=ajax.responseText;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please make it clear what your question is.

Comment: Are you sure the query is returning rows?

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: Where is $Monat coming from? I'd suggest doing something like $query = "SELECT * ..."; echo $query; $result = $mysqli->query($query); ... to make sure the $query is actually right.

Comment: The Query is right the $Monat is coming from $Monat = date("m");

Comment: if  you remove the second echo , what is happening? just asking :-) and  some dummy text in loop   echo $Tag.'asdf '.$Datum.' '.$Dienst.'';

Comment: If I remove the second echo and add dummy text to the first echo, the response is empty. But you can see here that it is giving out data: http://blaues-team.de/php/FTL_Month_2.php

Comment: then you know that its not even entering the loop

Comment: but when you open it in the browser you see that it does enter the loop... Please check the link, I am at my end here :(

Comment: You need to show the ajax because obviously it works on the page

Comment: What happens if you put the `onreadystatechange` method set _before_ calling `open` and `send` methods?

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, you should get all the data you want to return, and store it in a variable. after that, out of the loop, echo this variable.

Comment: I did as you suggested but still the reply is empty, whereas the browser says it's not: http://blaues-team.de/php/FTL_Month_2.php

Comment: Yes, please see my question, I added it just now.